# Anni's smoking habit has done seriously and potentially fatal damage to her lungs

Tags: grammaticality

- has done seriously and potentially  fatal damage to
- did damage that is seriously and potentially fatal
- damaged, serious and potentially fatally
- has done serious and potentially fatal damage to

Which will be the right answer and why???

Answer (score 2):

If you use "and" in a sentence to give two adjectives that operate on the same noun, they both have to work as if they were there on their own. In your example, "**seriously** and **potentially fatal**" are operating on the noun "damage".

You can't say "*seriously damage*" - the correct phrase would be "*serious* damage".

However, "potentially" operates as an adverb on the adjective "fatal", so that is correct. "*Fatal damage*" is correct, as is "*potentially* fatal damage".

So, the correct rendition of your entire sentence would be:

> Anni's smoking habit has done **serious** and **potentially fatal** damage to her lungs.

Comment: Your explanation isn’t  clear to me. Why I can't say " seriously damage"

Comment: "Seriously and potentially fatal damage" What's wrong here?? Can seriously and potentially modify fatal??? Adverb> Adjective>Noun is it right to sa???  Plz clear my confusio...

Comment: "Damage" in your example is a noun, not a verb. The damage done is serious. If "damage" is a verb, it is different. You could say: "smoking can seriously damage your lungs".

Comment: @Rony You **can** say "smoking can seriously damage your health", because that uses "damage" as a verb. But in your example sentence, "damage" is a noun, and you **can't** say "smoking has done seriously damage" because "seriously" is an adverb.

Comment: Is it right to say "seriously fatal" or can seriously modify fatal??

Comment: @Rony "Fatal" means it can kill you. Do you really need to make that any more serious? You cannot have gradations of something that is absolute, in any language I wouldn't have thought.